# [BadImageFormatException: Cannot load a reference assembly for execution.]

Tags: asp.net, dll, web-config

I had an ASP.NET project which was targeting at .NET Framework 4.6.1, I updated that to .NET Framework 4.8. After Clean and Rebuild the solution successfully, I am getting following:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Cannot load a reference assembly for execution.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Cannot load a reference assembly for execution.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[BadImageFormatException: Cannot load a reference assembly for execution.]

[BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime' or one of its dependencies. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058)]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +232
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +113
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +23
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +35
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +48

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime' or one of its dependencies. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058)]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +767
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +256
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +58
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +287
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +69
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +137
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +172
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +854

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime' or one of its dependencies. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058)]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +532
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +111
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +719

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.9032.0
```

I have simply checked the generate Binding Redirects on project properties. Which did some changes in the web.config file but still same issue persists.

I have .NET Framework 4.8 SDK installed.

As per my analysis, when I cleaned the solution. Some DLLs were deleted from BIN folder, and after Rebuilding the solution, they are never generating again.

Answer (score 1):

Its an old thread, but this answer could be helpful for someone in the future.
Try removing all the binding redirects. Then rebuild the solution and check the warnings in the error list. Double click on the binding redirects warning. VS should generate the required redirects automatically.
Clean and rebuild the solution.

Comment: This worked for me after a long fight. I'd recommend only deleting the full list of `<dependentAssembly>` nodes under `<assemblyBinding>` (and leave the assemblyBinding), then compile, double click the warning, and everything regenerates correctly afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

This can often occur when an assembly is built against a different version of .NET Framework than the one your application is targeting.

Here are some steps you can take to troubleshoot and resolve this issue:

Check your project's target framework: Ensure your project's target framework is correctly set to .NET Framework 4.8 in the project properties (right click on the project etc).

Reinstall NuGet Packages: Sometimes, a .NET Framework update can cause issues with the references in your NuGet packages. Try reinstalling the NuGet packages in your project. You can do this by right-clicking on the solution in Solution Explorer, selecting "Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...", then "Restore" to reinstall the packages.

Check your project's references: Look through the project's references in Solution Explorer and remove any that are not needed. For the remaining ones, check that they are the correct version for .NET 4.8.

Check the web.config: Look for any assembly binding redirects in the web.config file. These could be redirecting to a different version of the .NET Framework.

Clean and Rebuild: Clean the solution (right-click on the solution in Solution Explorer and select "Clean Solution"), then rebuild the solution (right-click on the solution in Solution Explorer and select "Rebuild Solution"). But you probably already did this.

Check your bin folder: After rebuilding, check your bin folder to ensure the required DLLs are present. If not, you might need to manually add them.

Manually delete the bin and obj folders: Sometimes, cleaning the solution doesn't remove all the old files, causing inconsistencies. Close Visual Studio, manually delete the bin and obj folders in your project, then reopen Visual Studio and rebuild the solution.

If the problem persists, please provide more details about the project's dependencies and the DLLs that are missing after the rebuild.